# What's the cause of this strange Java behavior?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I wanted to test the '==' operator on `Long`s and this is what I've found: the following code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Long n = 0L;
    final Long m = 0L;
    System.out.println(n + " == " + m + " : " + (n == m));

    final Long a = 127L;
    final Long b = 127L;
    System.out.println(a + " == " + b + " : " + (a == b));

    final Long A = 128L;
    final Long B = 128L;
    System.out.println(A + " == " + B + " : " + (A == B));

    final Long x = -128L;
    final Long y = -128L;
    System.out.println(x + " == " + y + " : " + (x == y));

    final Long X = -129L;
    final Long Y = -129L;
    System.out.println(X + " == " + Y + " : " + (X == Y));
}
```

outputs:

```
0 == 0 : true
127 == 127 : true
128 == 128 : false
-128 == -128 : true
-129 == -129 : false
```

The only explanation I could come up with was that the JVM stores all `long` values inside `[-128, 127]` in the Perm space, and gives their address to `Long`s and to everything outside the above range it creates a new allocation for each static value met in the code.

Am I close to being right? In what situations do we have to be aware of similar behaviors?

PS. I know I should use a `null`check and then `.equals()` to compare objects, but I was curious if anyone knew the answer.

**EDIT**

After **jtahlborn**'s answer who gave me the keyword **auto-boxing** I've found this great article with the [**well-documented answer**](http://www.javablogging.com/autoboxing-pitfalls-when-comparing-numbers-with/)

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  (And yes, using `==` here instead of `.equals` is a sin.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955958/with-abstract-datatypes-different-results-for-the-same-kind-of-conditions/11955984#11955984

Comment: You should NOT use a null check. Null checks are evil. Just don't use NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the result of auto-boxing.  See [Long.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29).

Answer (score 3):

`Long` has a internal cache for values from -128 to 127. if you create `Long` by `Long.valueOf(long)` method or autoboxing in this interval you always receive the same object for equals values. That's why '==' work for 0, 127 and -128 in your example.

If you create `Long` outside [-128, 127] then always will be created new instance if `Long` object. 
That's why '==' don't work for 128 and -129.

Have a look to `Long.valueOf(long)` source code.

Answer (score 1):

`-128 to +127` will be evaluated to true using `==` operator if you are `comparing object references`. The Long values(from -128 to +127) are put in a cache and returned multiple times, while higher and lower numbers generate `new Long` each time.

This is apllicable to primitive wrapper classes `Integer, Float` too. Try it for Integer and Float.

Comment: I am not downvoter, but I feel it needs little expalanation on how -128 t0 127 will be true?