# Puzzling behaviour of == after postincrementation

Tags: java, post-increment

Someone postulated in some forum thread that many people and even experienced Java Developers wouldn't understand the following peace of Java Code.

```
Integer i1 = 127;
Integer i2 = 127;
System.out.println(i1++ == i2++);
System.out.println(i1 == i2);
```

As a person with some interest in Java I gave it my thoughts and came to the following result.

```
System.out.println(i1++ == i2++);
// True, since we first check for equality and increment both variables afterwards.

System.out.println(i1 == i2);
// True again, since both variables are already incremented and have the value 128
```

Eclipse tells me otherwise. The first line is true and the second is false.

I really would appreciate an explanation.

Second question. Is this Java specific or does this example hold for example for the C based languages, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127

Comment: This question is extremely similar to the one posted by @DominikKunicki

Comment: Indeed, this is just a side effect of the integer cache. In both tests, you should be comparing the values instead of the identities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Integer i1 = 127;
Integer i2 = 127;
System.out.println(i1++ == i2++); 
// here i1 and i2 are still 127 as you expected thus true
System.out.println(i1 == i2); 
// here i1 and i2 are 128 which are equal but not cached
    (caching range is -128 to 127),
```

In case 2 if you use `equals()` it'd return true as `==` operator for integers only works for cached values. as 128 is out of cache range the values above 128 will not be cached, thus youhave to use `equals()` method to check if two integer instances above 127 are **true**

**TEST:**

```
Integer i1 = 126;
    Integer i2 = 126;
    System.out.println(i1++ == i2++);// true
    System.out.println(i1 == i2); //true



 Integer i1 = 126;
        Integer i2 = 126;
        System.out.println(i1++ == i2++);// true
        System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); //true

  Integer i1 = 128;
        Integer i2 = 128;
        System.out.println(i1++ == i2++);// false
        System.out.println(i1==i2); //false

  Integer i1 = 128;
        Integer i2 = 128;
        System.out.println(i1++.equals(i2++));// true
        System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); //true
```

Comment: As a note of caution, I believe the caching range is JVM implementation specific and not part of the JLS.  Therefore, this behaviour isn't guaranteed to be consistent across JVMs.

Comment: @ChrisKnight It's not implementation-specific, as it is in the specification. [Paragraph 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) states: *"If the value p being boxed is [...] an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2."*

Comment: @Mattias Buelens - We are both right.  To clarify, -128 to 127 (inclusive) is guaranteed.  However, JVM's may extend this cached range.  Further text in your reference:   "Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long values in the range of -32K to +32K.".

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Yes, meaning that all JVMs must cache -128/127, but a JVM might decide to also cache 128 for example.

Comment: @ChrisKnight Ah, I see what you mean now. Indeed, implementations may choose to extend the range. The specification also states: *"For other values, this formulation disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on the programmer's part."* In that sense, you're right about being cautious about this as you cannot rely on this extended range as a programmer.

Comment: can the downvoter leave a comment please .

Answer (score 1):

As explained this is due to [Integer caching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7-300). For fun, you can run the program with the following JVM option:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=128
```

and it will print true twice (option available on hostpot 7 - not necessarily on other JVMs).

Note that:

- this is JVM specific
- the modified behaviour is compliant with the JLS which says that all values between -128 and +127 *must* be cached but also says that other values *may* be cached.

Bottom line: **the second print statement is undefined in Java** and can print true or false depending on the JVM implementation and/or JVM options used.

Comment: Just ran it with that parameter - and still got False.

Comment: @AleksG It works with hotspot version 7u11.

Comment: With OpenJDK on 64-bit Linux it doesn't.

Comment: @AleksG As explained it is JVM specific.

Comment: See for example the comment in [this code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache) around line 585.

Comment: Possibly starting with java 7, however, also look at [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) in the specifications, where it states that it's always -128 to 127.

Comment: @AleksG No it says that -128/127 *must* be cached - but it also says that other values *may* be cached. Just wanted to point out that the result of the second condition in the OP's code is undefined and depends on VMs / Options.