# Comparing two Short objects giving unexpected results

Tags: java

I was executing following codes are got some surprising results

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Short i = 122, j = 122;
       if (i == j) {
            System.out.println("true");
       } else {
        System.out.println("false");
      }
    }
 }
```

and

```
 class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Short i = 1222, j = 1222;
       if (i == j) {
            System.out.println("true");
       } else {
        System.out.println("false");
      }
    }
 }
```

When I executed thses code, first code is giving `true` output while second code is giving `false` output.
I know when we compare Objects using `==` it doesn't look for the actual values, but just compares the references. But in first case, it's comparing the values while in second code it doesn't.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with how you're storing such a large value for a "short" type...

Comment: @MohammadS. 'Such a large value' as what? Shorts hold much bigger values than anything shown here.

Comment: @EJP  Sorry, I mixed up Java short with Java byte.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer wrapper objects share the same instances only within the value 127?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Short` has an internal cache for values ranging from -128 to 127. So for numbers within this range, the same instance of `Short` is returned. When you compare using ==, Java compares by instance, and so it returns `true`. When the numbers are outside this range, two different instances are created. Thus, they will fail this `==` comparison, returning `false`.

By having this caching we save some memory and have faster code.

Look into the following method from JDK 1.7 Source Code. This has been there since 1.5

```
public static Short valueOf(short s) {
        final int offset = 128;
        int sAsInt = s;
        if (sAsInt >= -128 && sAsInt <= 127) { // must cache
                return ShortCache.cache[sAsInt + offset];
        }
        return new Short(s);
    }
```

This caching is there for other wrapper classes as well; you can look into the Java documentation for more details.

Comment: This cache has *nothing* to do with processor cache memory. That statement is not at all relevant.

Comment: Max is correct.  On-chip caching (the "processor cache") has nothing to do with this question. The rest of the answer is correct, however.

Comment: I mean we need not to create any new instances, java will return same instances saving one Object's space.