# Funny stuff. Define this two variable to get an infinite loop?

Tags: java, variables

I have no idea to resolve this, k and i what type will be?

```
while (k<=i && i<=k && k!=i){
}
```

Comment: You're checking an impossible condition 

It is impossible for k to be less then or equal to i, i to be less then or equal to k and k and i to not be equal.

Comment: The closest I can think of is BigDecimal where `0.0` equals `0.00` is false but `0.0` compareTo `0.00` is 0.

Comment: @AbrahamP There are rare examples where impossible maths are true in Java, but this is not one them AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

```
Integer i = 128;
Integer k = 128;
```

Due to auto-boxing, these will be two distinct objects. `i <= k` and `k <= i` will both be true as the objects will be unboxed, but `i != k` will also be true since `==` and `!=` don't trigger unboxing.

But why are they different objects? Well, the JLS requires that [integers between -128 and +127 are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127). Outside of that range you'll usually get distinct objects. If you changed this to 127 instead of 128 then `i` and `k` would both reference the same `Integer` object.

Actually, technically, it's legal for Java implementations to cache additional values outside that range, so your mileage may vary here. A bulletproof example would explicitly create two objects, but I like the surprise factor of the code up top.

```
Integer i = new Integer(128);
Integer k = new Integer(128);
```

Comment: That depends on the size of the Integer cache.  Try `-129` ;)

Answer (score 1):

With autoboxing, `==` and `!=` compares references.  However `<=` `<` `>` and `>=` compare the contents unboxed values.

e.g.

```
Long i = -129;
Long k = -129;
```

The problem with using `Integer` as an example, is the upper limit as to when auto-boxing is cached varies.  It will be at least -128 to 127 but it could be much higher. e.g. with `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` it might be 10000 or 20000.  This means

```
Integer i = 128;
Integer k = 128;
```

May or may not be a solution depending on how the JVM is tuned.

---

The closest I can think of is BigDecimal where `0.0` equals `0.00` is false but `0.0` compareTo `0.00` is 0.

You would have to write the code as

```
while(k.compareTo(i) <= 0 && i.compareTo(k) <= 0 && !k.equals(i)) { }
```

and this could be an infinite loop for some values of BigDecimal.

Two examples of apparently impossible maths which work in Java are

```
while(x != 0 && x == -x) { }
```

and

```
while(x != x + 0) { }
```

There is a number of solutions for `x` which are in infinite loop ;)