# How to increase the cache size for Integer object

Tags: java, caching, java-6

While reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127)

I come to know that we can increase the size of cache through this comment

> The recent version of Java 6 support changing the maximum cache value to greater than 127

I google it but didnt find to do same.

Please help.

Comment: Don't use this to enable using `==` for `Integer` objects...

Comment: @chrylis it was just for learning. but can you please specify why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntegerCache for e.g. says this:

```
/**
 * Cache to support the object identity semantics of autoboxing for values between 
 * -128 and 127 (inclusive) as required by JLS.
 *
 * The cache is initialized on first usage. During VM initialization the
 * getAndRemoveCacheProperties method may be used to get and remove any system
 * properites that configure the cache size. At this time, the size of the
 * cache may be controlled by the vm option -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=<size>.
```

So either you use VM parameter or you use System property like:

```
-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=256
```

When launching the JVM.

Comment: where I need to define `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=256`.

Comment: While launching jvm like `java -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=256 MymainClass`

Comment: i am using eclipse :( how to do this in eclipse

Comment: Either in the run configuration you use to launch you class (VM arguments) or in the argument in the JRE definition (in the preferences, find where the JRE are defined, you can have JVM variables set for all runs on that JRE).

Comment: run as -> run configuration -> arguments -> vm arguments -> paste -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=256